# How can I convert char[] array to char*

Tags: c, string, char

I want to convert my `char[]` array to `char*` string in C programing language. Here is what I did. But I can't reach the solution . Please help me. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fnk(char *chr){
    printf("%s",chr);
}
int main(){
    char charfoo[100];
    int i=50;
    gets(charfoo);
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){

        fnk((char*) charfoo[j]);
    }

}
```

Comment: `for(int j=0;charfoo[j];j++){
        fnk(&charfoo[j]);
    }`

Comment: Whar exactly is `fnk` supposed to do in your code?

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean the following

```
fnk( &charfoo[i]);
```

Take into account that it would be better to write the loop the following way

```
for( int j=0; charfoo[j]; j++ ) {

    fnk( &charfoo[j]);
}
```

Also function `gets` is unsafe and is not supported any more by the C Standard. Instead use function `fgets` For example

```
fgets( charfoo, sizeof( charfoo ), stdin );
```

In this case the loop can look like

```
for( int j=0; charfoo[j] != '\0' && charfoo[j] != '\n'; j++ ) {

    fnk( &charfoo[j]);
}
```

If you want to output just one character in the function then the function should be defined like

```
void fnk(char chr){
    printf("%c",chr);
}
```

and called like

```
fnk( charfoo[j]);
```

Answer (score 1):

If we switch from `gets()` to `fgets()` as Vlad from Moscow suggests, then the return value from `fgets()` is of the same type as the argument to `fnk()` so we can just pass the result along:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fnk(char *string) {
    printf("%s", string);
}

int main() {
    char charfoo[100];

    fnk(fgets(charfoo, sizeof(charfoo), stdin));

    return 0;
}
```

The next step in sophistication would be to save the result of `fgets()` to a `char *` pointer and test if it's `NULL` or not before passing it along (or not) to `fnk()`.

If you want an actual `char *` copy of the array `charfoo[]` to exist in memory and not simply pass off `char[]` arrays as `char *` pointers, you could do the following which throws in lots of error checking too:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void fnk(char *string) {
    printf("%s", string);
}

int main() {
    char charfoo[100];

    char *input = fgets(charfoo, sizeof(charfoo), stdin);

    if (input != NULL) {

        char *string = strdup(input);

        if (string != NULL) {
            fnk(string);
            free(string);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But in all cases, it seems like you're making things more difficult than they need to be.

Answer (score 0):

Calling fnk with `i`  would just be the same call 50 time -- assuming you want to use `j` instead the code would look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
void fnk(char *chr){
    printf("%s",chr);
}
int main(){
    char charfoo[100];
    int i=50;
    gets(charfoo);
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++){
        fnk(charfoo + j);
    }
}
```

be aware that `gets` could cause buffer overflow if the input is longer than the charfoo (i.e. 99 bytes + newline + null) -- but that is a different story

Comment: sorry I edited it. but this is not solve my problems